# Xamarin Forms - C# - HttpUtility.ParseQueryString - automatically formats a string?

Tags: c#, json, wordpress, xamarin.forms, wordpress-rest-api

I'm doing a basic API request using the ParseQueryString operator.

When I pass a particular value through the ParseQueryString, it automatically formats it.

For example, if I pass example@example.com through the ParseQueryString, the returned result would be :

> example%40example.com

Which the server would return a null value.

However if the passed value is:

> example@example.com

Then it will work.

I understand that query strings normally don't have "@" but is there a way to pass the "@" to the API server?

Here's my code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

queryString["email"] = LoggedIn.LoggedInEmail;

var apiuri = "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?" + queryString;

Console.WriteLine(apiuri);
```

The returned API is:

> https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?email=example%40example.com

When it should display like so:

> https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?email=example@example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` method after you generate the apiuri.

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

queryString["email"] = LoggedIn.LoggedInEmail;

var apiuri = "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?" + queryString;

var url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(apiuri,Encoding.UTF8);
Console.WriteLine(url);
```